# different variable imputed values using same predictor variables mice R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, multi-level, r-mice

I would expect the imputed values of `x` to be the same if the same preditor variables were used, despite other variables being imputed or not, but it's not the case, as reproduced here:

```
library(data.table)
library(robustlmm)
library(mice)
library(miceadds)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)

# Data ------------------------------------

dt1 <- data.table(id = rep(1:10, each=3), 
                  group = rep(1:2, each=15),
                  time = rep(1:3, 10),
                  sex = rep(sample(c("F","M"),10,replace=T), each=3),
                  x = rnorm(30),
                  y = rnorm(30),
                  z = rnorm(30))

setDT(dt1)[id %in% sample(1:10,4) & time == 2, `:=` (x = NA, y = NA)][
           id %in% sample(1:10,4) & time == 3, `:=` (x = NA, y = NA)]


dt2 <- dt1 %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(y) %>% ungroup %>% as.data.table


# MI 1 ------------------------------------
pm1 <- make.predictorMatrix(dt1)
pm1['x',c('y','z')] <- 0
pm1[c('x','y'), 'id'] <- -2
imp1 <- mice(dt1, pred = pm1, meth = "2l.pmm", seed = 1, m = 2, print = F, maxit = 20)
# boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular - don't know how to interpret this (don't occur with my real data)
View(complete(imp1, 'long'))
                        
# MI 2 ------------------------------------
pm2 <- make.predictorMatrix(dt2)
pm2['x',c('y','z')] <- 0
pm2['x', 'id'] <- -2
imp2 <- mice(dt2, pred = pm2, meth = "2l.pmm", seed = 1, m = 2, print = F, maxit = 20, remove.constant = F)
# imp2$loggedEvents report sex as constant (don't know why) so I include remove.constant=F to keep that variable (don't occur with my real data)                      
View(complete(imp2, 'long'))
```

In `imp1`:

- `group`, `time` and `sex` are used to predict `x`
- `group`, `time`, `sex`, `x` and `z` are used to predict `y`

In `ìmp2`:

- `group`, `time` and `sex` are used to predict `x`
- `y` is complete so no imputation is performed for this variable

Given so, why are the results different for the imputed data on `x`?
Is it the expected behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: You have `remove.constant = F` in the `imp2` calculation, but not in the `imp1` calculation.  You should have it in both for comparability.  But fixing that still leaves the difference.  I think you'll have to ask the package maintainer for why.

Comment: Thank you @user2554330, I did that some minutes ago [#455](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/455) ;)

Comment: One guess:  since these are randomized methods, even though you say to start with `seed=1` both times, maybe the sequence of RNG calls is different in each case, and by the time it gets to imputing `x`, the seeds are different.

Comment: From the above issue I got to another one in `miceadds` package [#24](https://github.com/alexanderrobitzsch/miceadds/issues/24) There I get the information that the imputed values must not be the same), but I didn't get the "why" part. I was recommended to check [van Buuren missing data book](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/) but keeps unclear to me how matching algorithm really works

Comment: Sounds like you need to redo this question as a stats question on stats.stackexchange.com.  That's where you'll find imputation experts if the `miceadds` folks aren't helpful.